# Некорректная работа try\catch в цикле

Tags: c++, исключения, try-catch

1. Добрый день! Излагаю суть дела: есть проверка, согласно которой пользователь не должен ввести символы или ещё какую-то ерунду вместо обычного числа. 
   Использую try\catch внутри цикла, чтобы дать пользователю шанс занести правильные данные. В catch-е для пользователя дополнительно выводится уведомление, мол, Вы ошиблись, данные некорректно ввели.
   Однако есть проблема.  Во время первого прохода цикла в try проверяются введённые данные, я заведомо их вношу неправильно, чтобы получить второй шанс на ввод. Однако шанса этого нет. Уведомление, расположенное для пользователя в catch-е, зацикливается в консоли. 
       Путём экспериментов было установлено, что try просто не хочет работать последующие разы. Что делать? Помогите, пожалуйста, перепробовала уже всё.
2. Код:

   ```
   #include"Struct.cpp"
   #include"Functions.cpp"
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
     int counter, user_cost;//кол-во произведений; цена пользователя
     bool flag;
     cout << "How many pieces of art you wanna describe?" << endl;
     do
   {
        flag = true;
        try
      {
        cin >> counter;//ввод кол-ва описываемых произведений
        Art *PiecesOfArt = new Art[counter];//массив структур
        Input(PiecesOfArt, counter);//заполнение массива 
        Files(PiecesOfArt, counter);//запись данных в файл
        Output(PiecesOfArt, counter);//вывод структуры
        cout << endl << "Input your cost, please: ";//ввод пользовательской цены
        cin >> user_cost;
        Search(PiecesOfArt, counter, user_cost);//поиск и вывод удовлетворяющих лотов
        delete[]PiecesOfArt;//удаление динам. массива структур
      }
         catch (...)
        {
           flag = false;
           cout << "Incorrect input! Try again, please! "<< endl;
        }
   } while (!flag);

      system("pause");
      return 0;
    }
   ```
3. [image: Пример входящих данных, результат выполнения]

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных и что на выходе.

Comment: Просто вот [пример](https://pastebin.com/19Vwqyjk) и он работает так как надо. Ищите ошибки в логике. Ну или я чего-то не заметил.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: По-умолчанию в случае ошибки ввода поток ввода просто выставляет флаг ошибки, а не выбрасывает исключение. Для того, чтобы поток выбрасывал исклбчение в случае ошибки, ему необходимо установить соответствующий флаг `cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);` Но учтите, что в случае ошибки, символы, которые привели к этой ошибке, из потока не извлекаются. Также в вашем коде будет утечка памяти в случае вылета исклбчения между выделением и освобождением памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Решение ловить исключение в конструкции do / while логически неправильное.
Пишите например так:

```
bool flag = true;
while (flag)
{
    try
    {
      // ваши функции
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        flag = false;
        cout << "Incorrect input! Try again, please! "<< endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В блоке do while сначала выполняется тело цикла а потом проверяется условие .
Соответственно когда в блоке catch вы выставляете flag = false
условие (!flag) выдает true и вас возвращает в начало цикла .
Можно избавиться от данного эффекта перенеся

```
  flag = true;
```

в конец блока try :

```
     try
   {
     cin >> counter;//ввод кол-ва описываемых произведений
     Art *PiecesOfArt = new Art[counter];//массив структур
     Input(PiecesOfArt, counter);//заполнение массива 
     Files(PiecesOfArt, counter);//запись данных в файл
     Output(PiecesOfArt, counter);//вывод структуры
     cout << endl << "Input your cost, please: ";//ввод пользовательской цены
     cin >> user_cost;
     Search(PiecesOfArt, counter, user_cost);//поиск и вывод удовлетворяющих лотов
     delete[]PiecesOfArt;//удаление динам. массива структур
     flag = true
   }
```

но тогда вы выполните блок try 2 раза ( Если вы как-то подкорректируете данные для того чтобы исключения не возникало ). 
Добавив break в конец блока try получите рабочее решение :

```
try
{
 cin >> counter;//ввод кол-ва описываемых произведений
 Art *PiecesOfArt = new Art[counter];//массив структур
 Input(PiecesOfArt, counter);//заполнение массива 
 Files(PiecesOfArt, counter);//запись данных в файл
 Output(PiecesOfArt, counter);//вывод структуры
 cout << endl << "Input your cost, please: ";//ввод пользовательской цены
 cin >> user_cost;
 Search(PiecesOfArt, counter, user_cost);//поиск и вывод удовлетворяющих 
 //..лотов
 delete[]PiecesOfArt;//удаление динам. массива структур
 flag = true;
 break;
}
```